# Gatling - Problem when using the recorder on an applet

Tags: java, gatling, recorder

Question from a Gatling newbie here. I am having some issues trying to use the recorder on a java web application. I can start the recorder, log in to the app, go from pages to pages without issue, and this is recorded on Gatling as it is supposed to be, but when I try to go on a page where there is an applet, I face an error and the applet doesn't display itself. The webapp works as expected if I use it without the recorder.

Do you have any ideas on what could be causing this behavior?

The webapp is using a java 1.6 (and let's be fair, it is kinda a legacy application) and is hosted by our client. We must use Firefox version 3.0.9 to access it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: Gatling creator here.

I'm afraid we've never tried to support applets. Applets are a legacy technology, deprecated since Java 9 and will be dropped from java some day, so that's not something we plan on invest on.

That being said, contributions are welcome.